# Checkio Common Words Challenge: How do i continue?

Tags: javascript

I need your help since i'm stuck at the challenge from checkio.
What am i missing? I get back:

**Your result:*"one,two,three"*
Right result:*"one,three,two*"**

**The Challenge:**
*You are given two string with words separated by commas. Try to find what is common between these strings. The words are not repeated in the same string.
Your function should find all of the words that appear in both strings. The result must be represented as a string of words separated by commas in alphabetic order.*

**UPDATE**

this is my code:

```
function commonWords(first, second) {
const firstWord = first.split(',');
const secondWord = second.split(',');

let match = firstWord.filter(value => secondWord.includes(value));
return match.toString()
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match.toString()` doesn't change the value of `match` variable. You need to return it from the function.

```
function commonWords(first, second) {
   const firstWord = first.split(',');
   const secondWord = second.split(',');
   let match = firstWord.filter(value => secondWord.includes(value));
   return match.toString()
}
```

#### Explanation

There are two kinds of methods.

#### Mutator Methods

The first kind changes the original variable. You don't need to reassign the variable in case of those methods. Some of them are `reverse()`, `fill()`, etc

**Note:** These methods are only for reference type(objects, array) not for value types(string, number, boolean).

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr); //[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

#### Accessor Methods

The second type are those methods which doesn't change the original variables but it returns are new value which is used by assigning it to a variable using `=`. 
Some of them are `map()`, `filter()` etc.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.map(x => x * x); //This line has no impact at all 
console.log(arr) //Nothing is changed

arr = arr.map(x => x * x); //This line changes 'arr'
console.log(arr); //[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Now `toString()` is of second type(accessor method) type. Just calling that method never changes the original variable. You need to reassign or `return` according to your needs

Comment: thanks that solves the problem with brackets but now it seems that my implementation of the logic is wrong, could you maybe help with that too?

Comment: @OTRAY I have added a explanation. Ask anything if you are confused

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it!